Error Code: ConstraintTokenMint. Error Number: 2014. Error Message: A token mint constraint was violated
I am trying to create a staking program. When I test this code out, I get the subjected error:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use anchor_spl::token::{self, Mint, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer as SplTransfer};
use solana_program::system_instruction;

// This is your program's public key and it will update
// automatically when you build the project.
declare_id!("CXVv68e6ofmf4HF5myUCMP8YifhD69toz4PEeBrn6gkX");

#[program]
pub mod Staking {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        Ok(())
    }

}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        seeds = [b"vault".as_ref()],
        bump,
        token::mint = mint,
        token::authority = token_vault_account
    )]
    pub token_vault_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


test
import {
  createMint,
  createAssociatedTokenAccount,
  mintTo,
  TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
} from "@solana/spl-token";

describe("Staking", () => {
  it("initializes", async () => {
    // Generate keypairs for the new accounts
    const payer = pg.wallet.keypair;

    // Create a new mint and initialize it
    const mintKp = new web3.Keypair();
    const mint = await createMint(
      pg.program.provider.connection,
      pg.wallet.keypair,
      payer.publicKey,
      null,
      0
    );

    //Create Vault PDA
    const [VAULT] = await anchor.web3.PublicKey.findProgramAddress(
      [Buffer.from("vault")],
      pg.program.programId
    );

    const txHash = await pg.program.methods
      .initialize()
      .accounts({
        mint: mint,
        tokenVaultAccount: VAULT,
        signer: payer,
      })
      .rpc();
    console.log(`https://explorer.solana.com/tx/${txHash}?cluster=devnet`);
    await pg.connection.confirmTransaction(txHash, "finalized");
  });
});



At the top of my head some issues that come up

token::authority = token_vault_account - You are trying to set the token vault's authority as itself, yet this account hasn't been initialized.

I generally see this as an anti-pattern to the Associated Token Account design and would advocate for that approach when doing escrow-based programs


As such your Accounts struct would change like this
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = signer,
        associated_token::mint = mint,
        associated_token::authority = escrow_manager,
    )]
    pub token_vault_account: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

    #[account(
        init_if_needed, 
        payer = signer,
        space = 8 + 64 
        seeds = [b"admin".as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub escrow_manager: Account<'info, EscrowManager>

    pub mint: Account<'info, Mint>,
    pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
    pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

Then in your client side when deriving the ATA Vault Account,
   export const findEscrowManagerAddress = (): PublicKey => {
    return PublicKey.findProgramAddressSync(
        [Buffer.from("admin")],
        PROGRAM_ID
    )[0];
    };

    const txHash = await pg.program.methods
      .initialize()
      .accounts({
        mint: mint, 
        EscrowManager: findEscrowMangerAddress()
        tokenVaultAccount: getAssociatedTokenAddressSync(
                    mint,
                    findEscrowManagerAddress(),
                    true
                ),
        signer: payer,
        tokenProgram: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
        associatedTokenProgram: ASSOCIATED_PROGRAM_ID,
      })
      .rpc();


Hey Jimii. Thanks again. I was following a tutorial on YouTube for this. I'll try it out and post the update.
